# Chrome Flash sound gets broken and only a system restart fixes it

Tags: 12.04, sound, flash, google-chrome

I use Google Chrome 24.0.1312.52 (it happens on older Chrome versions too) on Ubuntu Precise with Shockwave (Pepper) Flash 11.5 r31. Occasionally the sound of the Flash player breaks and remains broken until I restart my system. This happens *especially* often when I play videos from `epicfail dot com`. Like every second video or so.

By "broken" I mean that it sounds like... er... well... farting. While it does seem to have something to do with the actual video sound (in terms of volume for example) it is absolutely unintelligible.

When the Flash sound is broken, it is broken for every flash instance - videos, games, etc. Restarting the browser or shift-esc -> plugin-shockwave-flash-> end-process does NOT fix it. The sound in other applications (Rhythmbox, Movie Player, Installed games) works fine. Only Flash seems to be affected.

Restarting the computer fixes it (until it gets broken again). So far it hasn't happened if I'm watching Youtube videos or playing Kongregate games. Epicfail is the surest way to break it, and it does happen every once in a while after a Wimp video.

So, has anyone experienced this? Is there a way of fixing it, or if not, at least getting it to work again without having to restart my machine?

Comment: The latest Chrome stable is 24.0.1312.52. Maybe you could try that?

Comment: no luck there too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just want to say that I ran into this problem and the solution was unexpected so I thought I'd share here.

There was another process using pulseaudio (a CLI music app) that starts on bootup, and I just have it paused when not using it. This process was monopolizing the flash player and preventing my browser from playing sound.

If anyone else runs into this, make sure to check and see if you have any other apps/processes using flash.

Answer (score 1):

Try restarting pulseaudio by sending a regular SIGTERM signal to it (it will recover). In the terminal run:

```
killall pulseaudio
```

That tends to fix the problem for me.

One more option is going to `chrome://plugins` (location bar), and disable "pepperflash".

Comment: I'm running Google Chrome too, but I don't have this "pepperflash" entry in the list of plugins. Perhaps you just mean the "Adobe Flash Player" entry?

Comment: Well recently the problem just disappeared. I don't know what specific update fixed it. Should I delete the question?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same symptom on Chrome v 26.0.1410.63 on Ubuntu 10.04. 
I have two Adobe Flash plugins registered in Chrome (both were enabled). When I **disabled** `/opt/google/chrome/PepperFlash/libpepflashplayer.so` (version 11.7.700.169) and left `/usr/lib/adobe-flashplugin/libflashplayer.so` (version 11.2 r202) **enabled**, the problem was fixed. I didn't even have to restart the browser.